# Merge with if() statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, merge, vlookup

I am trying to vlookup dataset two by the STUDY_ID. Dataset one has 450,000 rows with unique STUDY-IDs. Each STUDY_ID in dataset one has an INDEX_DATE. Dataset two has 2,000,000 rows of the same STUDY-IDs but with duplicates and different ADMIT_TIMEs. Dataset two has another variable CARE_SETTING (coded as "I"/"O"/"E"/"U").

I need to find the STUDY_IDs for whom INDEX_DATE==ADMIT_TIME and then, among them, those with multiple INDEX_DATE==ADMIT_TIME entries, if CARE_SETTING for all entries is the same (all "I", all "O", etc), then show one entry of "I","O",etc for CARE_SETTING; if any mixture of "O", "I", "E", "U", then show "I" for CARE_SETTING, if any other combination excluding "I", show "O" for CARE_SETTING.

Dataset 1 (df1)

| STUDY_ID | INDEX_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8-Oct-20 |
| 1235 | 13-Jul-20 |
| 1236 | 5-Jun-19 |
| 1237 | 18-Aug-20 |
| 1238 | 13-Jan-20 |
| 1239 | 12-Sep-20 |

Dataset 2 (df2) (for ease of reading typed * for dates equal to INDEX_DATE)

| STUDY_ID | ADMIT_TIME | CARE_SETTING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8-Oct-20* | E |
| 1234 | 8-Oct-20* | O |
| 1236 | 25-Feb-19 | I |
| 1236 | 28-Aug-20 | I |
| 1238 | 13-Jan-20* | I |
| 1238 | 13-Jan-20* | O |
| 1239 | 2-Feb-20 | E |
| 1239 | 12-Sep-20* | O |
| 1235 | 13-Jul-20* | E |
| 1235 | 13-Jul-20* | E |
| 1237 | 22-Mar-20 | O |
| 1237 | 12-Apr-20 | I |

Desired dataset

| STUDY_ID | INDEX_DATE=ADMIT_TIME | CARE_SETTING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8-Oct-20 | O |
| 1235 | 13-Jul-20 | E |
| 1238 | 13-Jan-20 | I |
| 1239 | 12-Sep-20 | O |

Comment: How does 1234 get "O" ? It has got two values "E" and "O".

Comment: Any combination of O, E, U gets "O". Any combination that includes "I" gets "I".

Comment: In your post you have mentioned `any mixture of "O", "I", "E", "U", then show "I" for CARE_SETTING`

Answer (score 2):

Join the two datasets by `'STUDY_ID'` and for each `STUDY_ID` decide the `CARE_SETTING` value using `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c('STUDY_ID', 'INDEX_DATE' = 'ADMIT_TIME')) %>%
  group_by(STUDY_ID) %>%
  summarise(CARE_SETTING = case_when(n_distinct(CARE_SETTING) == 1 ~ first(CARE_SETTING), 
                                     any(CARE_SETTING %in% "O") ~ "O", 
                                     any(CARE_SETTING %in% "I") ~ "I")) -> result
```

Comment: First, I need to take care of  INDEX_DATE=ADMIT_TIME, your approach does not address that

Comment: Do you want to check for `CARE_SETTING` only where `STUDY_ID` and `INDEX_DATE=ADMIT_TIME` matches? I have updated the answer to join accordingly. I am not clear about the conditions to get "I", or "O" values for `CARE_SETTING ` as you have different logic in your post, different in comments and expected output is different.

Comment: Thanks! It should now work with a little bit of modification.

Comment: The answer did not help.